# RichFaces component is getting rendered but broken

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to create a RichFaces application and because of some reasons I am using quite old versions i.e. I have to work with JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.0.1.

I have got the JSF 1.2 components working but when I am trying to create a simple page with a RichFaces component then component is getting render but it is broken. Below is actual and expected look and feel:

**Expected** (this from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/index.html#rich_dropDownMenu), code is also present over there, just scroll little below over there, my code is coming below):

[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

**I am getting menu options correctly but missing all those blue stuff and look-and-feel.**

It looked to me that some CSS or images are missing, but I am using the RichFaces JAR and there is no mention in the tutorial that additional images/css would be required so I am ruling out this.

Then I thought that it could be container issue, I checked RichFaces technical requirements and for Apache Tomcat it should not be greater than 6.0 (`Apache Tomcat 5.5 - 6.0`), and I was working on 7.x, so I jumped that bingo I found the issue, but alas that I got same issue even when I deployed in Tomcat 5.5.

As per best of my knowledge I am having correct configuration details and all required JARs, but considering the situation I am having feeling that I am missing some configuration or something else.

**richfaces_test_so.jsp:**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Add New User Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>

        <rich:dropDownMenu value="File" direction="bottom-right" jointPoint="bl">
            <rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" value="New" action="#{helloBean.addUser}"/>
            <rich:menuItem   submitMode="ajax"  value="Open" action="#{helloBean.addUser}"/>

            <rich:menuGroup value="Save As...">
                <rich:menuItem   submitMode="ajax" value="Text File"  action="#{helloBean.addUser}"/>
                <rich:menuItem   submitMode="ajax" value="PDF File"  action="#{helloBean.addUser}"/>
            </rich:menuGroup>

            <rich:menuItem  submitMode="ajax" value="Close" action="#{helloBean.addUser}"/>

            <rich:menuSeparator id="menuSeparator11"/>

            <rich:menuItem  submitMode="ajax" value="Exit"  action="#{helloBean.addUser}"/>
        </rich:dropDownMenu>


      </h:form>

    </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>jsftest_tomcat_5</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Ajax4JSF -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>greeting.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**List of my JARs:**

- ajax4jsf-1.1.1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.6.jar
- commons-el-1.0.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
- commons-io-1.3.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- commons-pool-1.3.jar
- el-ri-1.0.jar
- javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
- jsf-facelets-1.1.11.jar
- jstl-1.1.0.jar
- myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar
- myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar
- richfaces-3.0.1.jar
- tomahawk-1.1.6.jar

**Could someone please help me point out if I am missing something.** I have to work on RichFaces 3.0.1 and JSF 1.2, so please do not advise to work on latest versions.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't expect it to be answered by someone who has tendency to bring issues instead of resolving issues, or may be someone can't really resolve issues. Strange? BTW I tagged omnifaces, if this could catch attention of @BalusC

Comment: So you debugged amd did not see any 404's in the browser?

Comment: No, I have provided the actual screen shot of what I am getting. If you are trying out my example then let me know if you are getting 404.

Comment: I can't try out your example. It is not a [mcve], contains contradictory information so Sorry but it would take too much time for me that I cannot spend on either answering or at least helping to improve questions on non-medieval technology. And did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466726/richfaces-css-not-working

Comment: First of all you didn't show any screenshot that would confirm you're not getting 404's related to resources. It's certainly possible that the default skin in RichFaces 3.0.1 isn't blue, you may want to compare CSS files in RF 3.3 to rule this out.